# Stop Instagram Group Message Requests Spam

Tags: spam-prevention, instagram, instant-messaging

Instagram has a huge spam problem.

My "Message Requests" inbox is continually filled with requests to join Group Messages, sent by fake "sexy women" profiles.

The only options are to Accept, Ignore, or Delete these group message requests. There does not seem to be a way to report them as spam, or block the sender.

[image]

> Message Requests
> Requests aren't marked as seen until you allow them.
> Accept | Ignore | Delete
> Delete All

How can I prevent these messages from being sent to me? How can I block these senders or report them as spam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent random accounts from adding you to Instagram Message Groups. This should stop most of the Group Message Requests spam.

Instagram > Settings > Privacy > Messages > **Who Can Add You to Groups**

**NOTE:** this setting is present on some accounts, not accessible on others. Your account may not be able to access this setting.

[image]

> Settings > Privacy > Messages > Who Can Add You to Groups
>
> - Everyone on Instagram
>
>   - You can be added to groups by everyone, except by people you've blocked.
> - Only People You Follow on Instagram
>
>   - You can't be added to groups by anyone you don't follow. People you don't follow and haven't blocked will know that you don't allow everyone to add you to groups if they try to.